# Firebase realtime database: How to use onDisconnect

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I found out I can handle when a user close the app using `onDisconnect` but it doesn't work as I expected.

What I want to do is just remove a node when a user turn off the device or close the app. But the database never changed even when I turn off the emulator.

```
mBaseNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(...);
mBaseNode.child("aValue").onDisconnect.removeValue();
mBaseNode.addValueEventListener()...
```

I might misunderstand about `onDisconnect`. What am I wrong with this?

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind this is `onDestroy()` is often not called at all. Often the system just kills the process without any callbacks. Knowing when `onDestory()` would be fired is a bit tricky.

It fires mainly when client and server get disconnected.

There are two cases that may happen when the client and server are disconnected:

1. the client explicitly disconnects from the server
2. the client simply disappears

When you kill the app, you are triggering an explicit disconnect. In that case the client will send a signal to the server that it is disconnecting and the server will immediately execute the `onDisconnect()` callback.

When you switch off wifi, your app doesn't get a chance to tell the server that it is disconnecting. In that case the `onDisconnect()` will fire once the server detects that the client is gone.

This may even take a few minutes, depending on how the time-outs for sockets are configured. So in that case you just have to be a bit more patient, which means it would not be looking good in your real app.

So I'd advise you to remove the value in `onPause()` method of your activity, like this:

```java
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        final DatabaseReference rRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(toBeDeleted);

        rRef.child(yourWishChild).removeValue();


    }
```

Comment: I think `onPause` occurs other than when the user turn off the device or close the app.

Comment: `onPause()` is fired whenever the user leaves that particular activity. So you can implement your thing using `onPause()` on different activities.

Comment: you mean finishing an activity? or even starting a new activity?

Comment: @nani both, because leaving an activity implies finishing one activity or starting another. But you can always reset the value of the desired node in the start of the new activity which is started.

Comment: Actually I don't want to remove the node when starting a new Activity. I want to do it only when finishing the activity.

Comment: Unfortunately, `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` both have similar issues as I have stated in the answer, so your only plausible approach should be `onPause()`, it not only would be fired at the very precise moments, it would also not be having any issues. The only issue that you might face is that it will remove value from the node if user moves to different activity, but that can be fixed by again putting the same value at the start of `onCreate()` method of that activity.